# How to make python use latest SQLite

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, python3, sqlite

I already did the following:

```
1. Going over to this url: https://sqlite.org/download.html I will download 'sqlite-autoconf-3260000.tar.gz' which is version 3.26.0 
2. assuming it's in my Downloads folder I will open my terminal and type in the following commands
3. I am assuming you have build-essentials installed if not run
# sudo apt install build-essentials -y
# cd ~/Downloads
# tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3260000.tar.gz -C /tmp/
# cd /tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3260000
# ./configure
# make
# make install
# make clean
close your terminal and open it again
# sqlite3 --version
```

When I do sqlite3 --version it says I'm using 3.26.0
But when I do:

```
Import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

It says I'm using 3.22.0 (the previous installed version)
Does anyone know how I can make python use the latest version?
I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I believe python uses a built-in sqlite module but maybe this will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/26369430/3417978

Comment: No,  and yes, the inbuild one is just a handler that uses the sqlite3 installed on the OS